# Jquery animations works slowly

Tags: jquery

I have got this html

```
    <div class='obuserposts'>
      <div class="obdef">Order By</div>
      <div class="nobdef">Number of likes</div>
      <div class="nobdef">Number of comments</div>
      <div class="nobdef">Upload date(newest first)</div>
      <div class="nobdef">Upload date(oldest first)</div>
    </div>
```

and this jquery

```
    $(".obuserposts").click(function(event) {
      $(".nobdef").slideDown('400');
    });
```

It works but before working it delays for 1 second.
Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24mcn20f/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle css, there are some animations for the classes *obuserposts* and *nobdef*.
Deleting the following lines results in a smoother transition:

```
-webkit-transition: .25s;
-moz-transition: .25s;
-ms-transition: .25s;
-o-transition: .25s;
transition: .25s;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Indeed it did.Thanks!